# WPF application: upload image from Google Drive to Google+

Tags: c#, wpf, web-services, api, google-plus

C#.
Hi, I basically have to program a library (.dll) that has the necessary to communicate with Google Drive. Then the WPF application has to get the image and post it on Google+.
The user has to be able to: See his files, find an image, select it and post it.

Could someone guide me though the basics of how to do this, I don't need anything complex, just a basic WPF app that does this.

I already know the basic concepts of Web Services and Reflection.

Thank you very much! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find full information about interact with google drive with C# by ref:

https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-cs

For interact with Google+ try read this article:

https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/csharp